# Is it possible to run two YOLO (yolov4) object detection models in a single application?

Tags: python, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo, yolov4

I understand that it would be much simpler to just train YOLOv4 accordingly but:
I have limited computational resources and was hoping I could combine pre-trained models I found online, saving my time, or train a model and combine it with other models available online.

If I have one '.weights' file of a custom object detector that detects *traffic signs* and another '.weights' file of detector that detect *pedestrians*. Is there a way to combine these models, so that when run on a video/image (or in real-time capture), it detects pedestrians and traffic signs **simultaneously**.

**By combining I mean**, either to edit the 'weights' file somehow to achieve this, or editing the python code (while running the detector) that gets this done. (or any other way)

If not possible - is there any way to make them run in a sequence, efficiently?

Comment: Retraining on Colab might be an easier option for you if computational resource is your problem. But [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54548361/combining-two-pre-trained-models-with-2-different-classes-dataset-for-predicti) might help you too

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Edit: I do use Colab but they recently locked me out for overusing, and Colab Pro is unavailable where I live :/

Comment: I usually use multiple accounts and they have their own shifts

Comment: Yeah, Was checking just now if I have regained access, otherwise would do that :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to do that. Create two different python files and load the model in them. Then create a new file and initialise both of them in the new file. Then take the continous video / image feed as an input, the file will give output of detected traffic signs. Use this output as an input to your pedestrian problem.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import time
margin = 20


import detection_cls
run = detection_cls.Ppe_Detection_1()




class Ppe_Detection():

    def __init__(self):
        self.weightfile = 'yolov4_pretrained.weights'
        self.cfgfile = 'cfg/yolov4_pretrained.cfg'
        self.PpeNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(self.weightfile,self.cfgfile)
        self.classes = self.get_classes()
        layer_names = self.PpeNet.getLayerNames()
        self.output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in self.PpeNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

                            # = [self.PpeNet.getLayerNames()[(i[0] - 1)] for i in self.PpeNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    def get_classes(self):
        # self.classes = []

        with open("coco.names","r") as f:
            self.classes_val = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]


        return self.classes_val

    def detection(self,img):


        start = time.perf_counter()
        height,width,channels = img.shape

        # Detecting objects
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,0.00392,(416,416),(0,0,0),True,crop=False)
        self.PpeNet.setInput(blob)
        outs = self.PpeNet.forward(self.output_layers)
        time_took = time.perf_counter() - start
        fps = str(int(1/time_took))

        # getting the list
        class_ids = []
        confidences = []
        boxes = []

        for out in outs:
            for detection in out:
                # print(detection)
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]

                if confidence > 0.4:
                    # object detected
                    center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                    center_y = int(detection[1]*height)

                    w = int(detection[2]*width)
                    h = int(detection[3]*height)

                    # Rectangle Coordinates
                    x = int(center_x-w/2)
                    y = int(center_y-h/2)

                    boxes.append([x,y,w,h])
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    class_ids.append(class_id)


        indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes,confidences,0.4,0.4)


        info = []
        if len(indexes) > 0:
            for i in indexes.flatten():
                x,y = boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1]
                w,h = boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]

                conf = confidences[i]
                if x<0:
                    x = 0
                if y < 0:
                    y = 0
                type = '{}'.format(self.classes[class_ids[i]])
                info.append([x,y,w,h,type,conf])

        new_frame_time = time.time()


        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            for i in indexes:
                x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
                label = str(self.classes[class_ids[i]])
                color = (0,0,145)
                # cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,2)
                cv2.putText(img,fps,(10,30),font,3,color,3)
                cv2.putText(img,label,(x,y+30),font,3,color,3)

        # print(boxes,confidences,class_ids)
        # print("opened")
        # print(info)
        return info

    def cropping_detection(self):

        count = 0
        cropped_frame = []
        value_img = []
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while cap.isOpened():

            r,f = cap.read()
            # counts +=1

            detection = ppe.detection(f)

            try:
                x,y,w,h,cls,conf = detection[0]
            except Exception as e:
                pass



            # for i in range(len(detection)):
                # print(detection[i])
            try:
                if cls=='person':
                    print("Person detected")

                    cropped_img = f[y-margin:y+h+margin,x-margin:x+w+margin]

                    # print(cropped_img)
                    # value = ppe.detection(cropped_img)

                    final = run.detection(cropped_img)

                    print('final',final)

                    # print(value)
                    # print(cropped_img)

                    # value_img.append(value)
                    # cropped_frame.append(cropped_img)
                    # cv2.imwrite("data/frame%d.jpg" % count, cropped_img)
                    cv2.imshow("Hi",cropped_img)
                    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff==ord('q'):
                        break
                    # count += 1

                else:
                    pass
            except Exception as e:
                print("In except part")



        # cap.release()
        # cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        # print(cropped_img)
        return value,cropped_img







ppe = Ppe_Detection()
ppe.cropping_detection()
# ppe.get_classes()
# ppe.run_video()
# take_photo()
# inference_image()
```

The function that I've imported here can be found below

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import time




class Ppe_Detection():

    def __init__(self):
   
     self.weightfile = 'backup/yolov3_best.weights'
        self.cfgfile = 'yolov3.cfg'
        self.PpeNet = cv2.dnn.readNet(self.weightfile,self.cfgfile)
        self.classes = self.get_classes()
        layer_names = self.PpeNet.getLayerNames()
        self.output_layers = [layer_names[i - 1] for i in self.PpeNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]

                            # = [self.PpeNet.getLayerNames()[(i[0] - 1)] for i in self.PpeNet.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
    def get_classes(self):
        # self.classes = []

        with open("obj.names","r") as f:
            self.classes_val = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]


        return self.classes_val

    def print_all(self):
        print(self.classes)

    def detection(self,img):


        start = time.perf_counter()
        height,width,channels = img.shape

        # Detecting objects
        blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img,0.00392,(416,416),(0,0,0),True,crop=False)
        self.PpeNet.setInput(blob)
        outs = self.PpeNet.forward(self.output_layers)
        time_took = time.perf_counter() - start
        fps = str(int(1/time_took))

        # getting the list
        class_ids = []
        confidences = []
        boxes = []

        for out in outs:
            for detection in out:
                scores = detection[5:]
                class_id = np.argmax(scores)
                confidence = scores[class_id]

                if confidence > 0.4:
                    # object detected
                    center_x = int(detection[0]*width)
                    center_y = int(detection[1]*width)

                    w = int(detection[2]*width)
                    h = int(detection[3]*height)

                    # Rectangle Coordinates
                    x = int(center_x-w/2)
                    y = int(center_y-h/2)

                    boxes.append([x,y,w,h])
                    confidences.append(float(confidence))
                    class_ids.append(class_id)


        indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes,confidences,0.4,0.4)


        info = []
        if len(indexes) > 0:
            for i in indexes.flatten():
                x,y = boxes[i][0], boxes[i][1]
                w,h = boxes[i][2], boxes[i][3]

                conf = confidences[i]
                if x<0:
                    x = 0
                if y < 0:
                    y = 0
                type = '{}'.format(self.classes[class_ids[i]])
                info.append([x,y,w,h,type,conf])

        new_frame_time = time.time()


        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
        for i in range(len(boxes)):
            for i in indexes:
                x,y,w,h = boxes[i]
                label = str(self.classes[class_ids[i]])
                color = (0,255,145)
                cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),color,2)
                cv2.putText(img,fps,(10,30),font,3,color,3)
                cv2.putText(img,label,(x,y+30),font,3,color,3)

        # print(boxes,confidences,class_ids)
        # print("opened")
        print(info)
        return info




ppe = Ppe_Detection()
ppe.get_classes()
ppe.print_all()


#############
def inference_image():
    img = cv2.imread("sumit_off.jpg")
    ppe.detection(img)
    cv2.imshow("Image",img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


def run_video():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while cap.isOpened():
        r,f = cap.read()
        try:
            info = ppe.detection(f)
        except Exception as e:
            print("______",e)
        cv2.imshow("image",f)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q") :
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

run_video()
```